# Помогите сделать проверку по базе Mysql

Tags: mysql

у меня есть форма, теперь я введу туда `john@test.com` нажму `enter` произойдет проверка по базе `MySQL` на наличие такого e`mail'a if{такого емайла не существует}else{такой емайл существует}`. Как реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или можно делать count:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM user WHERE поле='значение'")) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row['c'] > 0) {echo 'Ok';}
    else {echo 'No';}
    $result->close();
}
else
{
    echo 'Что-то пошло не так';
}
```

Comment: да много чего можно сделать :) Было бы у ТС желание, а то по такой постновке вопроса желания-то и нет :) Я этот ответ нагуглил по запросу `mysql php проверить наличие строки в базе`

Answer (score 2):

```
$res = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `поле`='значение' AND `поле`='значение'  AND `поле`='значение'"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) { 
echo 'OK'; 
} else { 
echo 'NO'; 
}
```